# When adding a tag to my question I get weird AJAX

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow

This error pops up as a tag normally would after typing the FULL keyword in the box:

> Authentication successful. Click here
>   if you are not redirected within 5
>   seconds.(undefined)

This is AFTER I type in "sql". Before I finish the word it seems to be suggesting everything properly.

Edit: After getting home, I can't reproduce (this bug).

Comment: This is very strange behavior, cannot reproduce or locate anything in the source to trigger this. Is it possible to use Firebug to find the post/response from the AJAX request? This would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the message that came up has to do with the fact that I was at work. I found out that our system there has to authenticate you (by opening a browser) and it will show that message. I'm not sure why it is doing it in this case but I guess it's not really an issue directly with Stackoverflow.